# Python webscraping xpath that contains spaces and enter

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get href of a class in Beautifulsoup. The path i am looking for, has a class that contains spaces and a new line. I want to be able to extract "https://www.website.com/"

```
<a class="this is part1 
      this is part2" target="_self" href="https://www.website.com/">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can just use `dictionary` instead of `__class`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<a class="this is part1 this is part2" target="_self" href="https://www.website.com/">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('a', {'class': 'this is part1 this is part2'}).get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`class="this is part1 this is part2"` means that the tag has class `this`, `is`, `part1` and `part2`. You can use CSS selector `.this.is.part1.part2` to select it:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    """<a class="this is part1 
    this is part2" target="_self" href="https://www.website.com/">""",
    "html.parser",
)

url = soup.select_one("a.this.is.part1.part2")["href"]
print(url)
```

Prints:

```
https://www.website.com/
```